Are disks in multi-bay enclosure seen as individual disks or one?
I have only experience with single disk enclosure, so sorry for naive question.
Let's say I buy 2-bay disk enclosure and put there 2 disks. Will I see them as two separate disks (this is what I would like) or the enclosure controller somehow will merge those disks and I will see only single one?
Or it is enclosure dependent and with some I will not see individual disks?
Background: I have NUC running Linux, and I would like to permanently connect 2-bay enclosure and -- as the storage goes -- have an effect of running full-size computer with two disks inside.

It generally depends on the enclosure. Some support RAID, some don't. Those that do may or may not be configurable.

They should show up as individual disks – likely as a single USB device with multiple SCSI LUNs (each appearing as an independent /dev/sd* disk). Though enclosures with a RAID feature do exist, but I think that's always optional.
Most likely, though, it won't reach the full performance of "two disks inside".
(Speaking of performance, I got particularly unlucky with my two-disk USB SATA dock that only allows one operation at a time – if one disk is busy, the other cannot be accessed… Hopefully your full-size enclosure does a better job at that.)

Many thanks for the answer and your remark, this would lead to far worse setup that I am hoping for (I use slow 5400 rpm disks, but in regular computer I can copy files without such hiccups as you describe).

Well, even assuming yours happens to have the same kind of problem, it might not be a problem for copying files in general... though if you use both, then a shared USB connection would still be a bit slower when compared to two fully independent SATA (or even USB) connections. Try it and see; I don't have much experience in that area.

You can consider a NAS, which is somewhat similar, except you hook it up using ethernet. Speeds are often faster that way, and no problem in accessing 2 disks at the same time.
